# Performance issue with WCF-Custom sapBinding

Tags: performance, wcf, sap, biztalk, biztalk-2009

We are experimenting problems with a **WCF-Custom** Send Port in BizTalk Server 2009.

Our Send Port is using **sapBinding** and is very slow. Checking our Performance Counters, the problem is with **Outbound Adapter Latency (sec)**, that sometimes is greater than 5 secs, when the process in SAP is only ms.

How can we check where is exactly the problem? Enabling **enablePerformanceCounters** property on binding can help with this issue?

**UPDATE**
I have added the WCF Microsoft.Adapters.SAP Diagnostics and now I can see exactly the invocation time:

[image: Invocation time]

I don't understand where the time is lost.

Comment: Yes, enabling the performance counters may give you more information to determine where the issue is. Note: They may make the initial startup of the port a bit slower as it then has to initialise those counters.